# Do the effects of the Antimagic Field spell affect the person who cast it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

We can't figure out if the person who cast *[antimagic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)* is also not able to cast magic or use magic items. If this is the case, what would be the use for the spell, as you are just as weak as the people you are affecting?

Comment: If you find an answer to your question from something down below you may accept that answer by clicking the check mark by the name of the answer. If you have done it right the check mark will turn green.

Answer (score 8):

#### Nothing in the spell description excludes the caster from the effect.

*Antimagic field* states:

> A 10-foot-radius invisible sphere of antimagic surrounds you. This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse. Within the sphere, spells can't be cast, summoned creatures disappear, and even magic items become mundane. *Until the spell ends, the sphere moves with you, centered on you.*
>
> *Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.* A slot expended to cast a suppressed spell is consumed. While an effect is suppressed, it doesn't function, but the time it spends suppressed counts against its duration.

You are always inside of an *antimagic field* that you cast, and since nothing in the spell description makes you immune to its effects, you are affected.

#### *Antimagic field* is a trade off that you usually win if you have friends who aren't magic users.

So you can't cast any other spells. You can't be affected by them either, nor can anyone else inside the sphere cast spells or be affected by them.

In my experience, *antimagic field* is best used in tandem with martial characters to take down a powerful magic wielding boss. In one game, I played a wizard in a party with a monk, a fighter, a barbarian, and a cleric. We defeated a Lich with little issue using *antimagic field*. The poor lich couldn't use any of his magic, and had no chance at winning a grapple contest with the barbarian. They beat him to death in 2 rounds while I stood around and watched.

Comment: You didn't just stand around watching, you dynamically maintained control over the available options of your competitors!

Answer (score 4):

#### The spell's description does not exclude the caster from the effects.

In the spell's description there is not anything that specifies that the caster is not affected by the spell's effects. As already stated in [Thomas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/185300/63061)' and [DeathClawProductions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206600/63061)' answers, the following bit from the spell text asserts that

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

Moreover, the sections in the spell description about **Targeted Effects**, **Areas of Magic**, **Spells** and **Magic Items** do not exclude the caster from the *Antimagic Field*: if there was any exception, it would have been  addressed here.

#### The Area of Effect of this spell includes the point of origin, hence the caster.

There are some areas of effect that do not include the origin point of the spell (*e.g.*, [cone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#Cone)). Antimagic Field is a sphere centered on the caster, hence the point of origin is "inside" the caster: such point is *included* in the AoE, as one can read in spellcasting [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#Sphere):

> **Sphere**
>
> You select a sphere’s point of origin, and the sphere extends outward from that point. The sphere’s size is expressed as a radius in feet that extends from the point.
>
> A sphere’s point of origin is included in the sphere’s area of effect.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't see any reason why the caster wouldn't be.**

> A 10-foot-radius invisible sphere of antimagic surrounds you. This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse.
> Within the sphere, spells can't be cast, summoned creatures disappear,
> and even magic items become mundane. Until the spell ends, the sphere
> moves with you, centered on you.
>
> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact
> or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it. A
> slot expended to cast a suppressed spell is consumed. While an effect
> is suppressed, it doesn't function, but the time it spends suppressed
> counts against its duration.

Looking at the spell's description, there's nothing that makes it to where the user that casted it is excluded, and since the caster would always be in the field that they casted, the caster is also affected by it.